# why I get distorted JSON mqtt payload from aws iot?

Tags: json, aws-sdk, aws-iot

I have a lambda function trigger by iot topic 
the lambda function also print out the iot message as the following:

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  console.log('string',event)
  console.log('JSON.stringify:',JSON.stringify(event));
};
```

when I am sending

```
{
  "desired": {
    "one": {
        "two": "is two"
    }
  }
}
```

I got

```
{
    "two": "is two" 
}
```

I am missing one level of my message can anyone explain why this happened?

Comment: Can you post your AWS IoT Rule?

Comment: I found the solution for that , I used different sql version in iot rule 2016-03-23 instead of 2015-10-08 and now it works,